# ASP.net TreeView bound to XML does not refresh

Tags: asp.net, xml, data-binding, treeview

I'm working for the first time on an ASP.net project, please forgive me if my problem seems obvious.

I have a treeview bound to an XMLDataSource.

The binding is as follows on the page_load

```
            dsXMLAlarms.Data = _client.ActiveAlarmsXML;
            tvAlarms.DataSource = dsXMLAlarms;
            tvAlarms.DataBind();
```

The first time the program runs, the Treeview (tvAlarms) shows the correct data. However, if the background data alters (in this case _client.ActiveAlarmsXML returns different content) and the page is refreshed, the Page_load runs, _client.ActiveAlarms updates the Data property of the DataSource but the treeview remains the same. i.e. it's as though the data has not changed BUT it has. If the program is reset (and the background data has not changed) the Treeview once again shows the correct data - which I expected when the page was previously refreshed. It's as though the Treeview is remembering data in between page refreshes (and I have tried CTRL-F5) to make sure that the browser cache is cleared.

Can someone please shed any light on what I'm (obviously) doing wrong? And very helpfully, tell me how to force a treeview refresh from the code-behind when a background (WCF Service callback) event is fired.

Thanks